# libvips get error in converting png to avif via svt convertor ( centos7)

Tags: avif, libvips

Someone could describe me how i can fix it? I tried install other convertor (aom)
Update your OS or use another non-solution.

images with other extensions are converted successfully
jpg -> avif(ok), png -> webp(ok), jpg -> webp (ok), png -> avif(fail)

```
vips copy convertable.png convertable.avif
Svt[info]: -------------------------------------------
Svt[info]: SVT [version]:   SVT-AV1 Encoder Lib v1.8.0
Svt[info]: SVT [build]  :   GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)    64 bit
Svt[info]: LIB Build date: Mar  4 2024 16:44:03
Svt[info]: -------------------------------------------
Svt[warn]: If you are using tiles with the intent of increasing the decoder speed, please also consider using --fast-decode 1, especially if the intended decoder is running with limited multi-threading capabilities.
Svt[info]: Number of logical cores available: 4
Svt[info]: Number of PPCS 74
Svt[info]: [asm level on system : up to avx]
Svt[info]: [asm level selected : up to avx]
Svt[info]: -------------------------------------------
Svt[info]: SVT [config]: main profile   tier (auto) level (auto)
Svt[info]: SVT [config]: width / height / fps numerator / fps denominator       : 240 / 184 / 60000 / 1000
Svt[info]: SVT [config]: bit-depth / color format                   : 8 / YUV420
Svt[info]: SVT [config]: preset / tune / pred struct                    : 5 / PSNR / random access
Svt[info]: SVT [config]: gop size / mini-gop size / key-frame type          : 321 / 32 / key frame
Svt[info]: SVT [config]: BRC mode / rate factor                     : CRF / 32 
Svt[info]: -------------------------------------------
Svt[error]: Invalid API input buffer size detected. Please ignore the output stream
```

I tried install other convertor but aom version is not support (centos7). In ubuntu all work fine.